# Building an api with several arrays which can be updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to noSQL and i'm trying to figure out how to create the best possible model structure. What i need to do is every hour to retrieve leagues and matches from an api and add it to my database. Every hour the score might change and new matches might be added to each league and therefor this should be possible in the model. i've read the documentation and created following, however i'm not sure it is possible to update each and add new matches to leagues. What is the ideal modelling for such?

**Tournament model**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
var League     = require('./league');

var TournamentSchema = new Schema({
    slug: String,
    tournaments: [League]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tournament', TournamentSchema);
```

**League**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
var Match    = require('./match');

var leagueSchema   = new Schema({
    leaguetId: Number,
    name: String,
    matches: [Match]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('League', leagueSchema);
```

**Match**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var matchSchema   = new Schema({
    homeTeam: String,
    awayTeam: String,
    homeScore: Number,
    awayScore: Number,
    start: Date


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', matchSchema);
```

**Post request so far**

```
router.post('/tournaments', function(req, res, next) {

      var tournament = new Tournament();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
       tournament.name = req.body.slug;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

       // save the bear and check for errors
       tournament.save(function(err) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);

           res.json({ message: 'Tournament created!' });
       });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding new matches to leagues and updating matches on a timed interval, why nest them within each other? Lets say you have a match with id 5 whose score changed. In order to find it to update it you'd have to first go through each league, and then iterate through each match in each league until you find the match with id 5. Unless I'm mistaken and there's some easier way to do it, this seems very inefficient.

Why not have two collections? A league collection and a match collection. There will be a 1 (league) : many (match) relationship. When you need to update a match's score, who cares what league it's in? Search the match collection for id 5, and update it.

What would a new match look like? Lets say a league with id 7 had a new match. Add a match to the match collection that has a league id of 7.

If you're really opposed to moving away from one collection.. at least store your matches in an object instead of an array, that way you can find matches with an O(1) lookup time by using it's match name. Instead of O(n) or O(n^2) lookup time like you currently have.

Comment: Seems like a better option, however how would i create these relationships? so i can be able to create the right json api

Comment: I alluded to it in my answer, but you maybe didn't catch it. A 1 to many relationship between two collections. Make a foreign key in the match collection called league id. Each match has a league id on it's record. That's how you can relate the two collections together. I take it you've not worked with SQL before?

Comment: I can tell based on the comments that you left in the code snippets that you copy pasted this from the node tutorial by scotch.io. I strongly recommend not using mongoose. Use the native node driver, and start slow. Start with basics like "how to query mongo". Feel free to contact me outside of this thread with other questions you may run into.

Comment: Ohh okay so foreign key just like in SQL. i was convinced that you nested the different objects into and didnt used foreign keys in noSQL. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Why should i not use mongoose. seems like an easier way syntax wise?

Comment: If i should use native code driver, i might as well just switch to Postgres, since i'm familiar with that. I chose mongodb, because it seemed more supported in node.

Comment: Joins are coming to mongodb: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Why mongo driver and not mongoose? 
1. using an ORM is not an excuse for not knowing how to use native queries. It's easy at first but as soon as you want to do something outside of the norm, it gets hard fast.
1a. Your ORM doesn't always do the right thing. 
1b. mongoose can't do everything you need it to.
2. Mongoose is slow
3. Mongoose documentation sucks and is sometimes wrong.
etc.

Comment: On that note, if you're familiar with postgres, check out knex.js. It makes working with SQL databases painless.